# Using Fetch api with spring controllers

Tags: spring, fetch

I have this controller method

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")
        //@Produces("application/json")
        @ResponseBody
        @RequestMapping(value = { "/test_api" }, method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String test_api(){
        String message = "logan";
        return message;

        }
```

and this script that i want to use to get to return the message in my controller

This is the javascript

```
fetch('http://localhost/boilerplate/test_api', {
                        mode: 'no-cors'
                        }).then(function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                            });
```

I get a null when i look at the body

```
Response {type: "opaque", url: "", redirected: false, status: 0, ok: false, …}
body
:
null
bodyUsed
:
false
headers
:
Headers {}
ok
:
false
redirected
:
false
status
:
0
statusText
:
""
type
:
"opaque"
url
:
""
__proto__
:
Response
```

Any idea why the body is empty of the returned object?.